# Is it possible to selectively sync cookbooks with knife bootstrap?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, chef-infra, knife, cookbook

I'm trying to get a server up and running via knife bootstrap via this command:

```
knife bootstrap "<ip-address>" 
-x ec2-user 
-r recipe[connector],recipe[all-servers] 
-N "serv-name" 
-E staging 
-i "~/.chef/mycert.pem" 
--sudo 
--no-host-key-verify
```

The all-servers recipe includes dependencies for windows that are broken in chef 13+:

(TLDRS, full stack traces are at the bottom)

```
13: undefined method “kernel” (outdated 7-zip cookbook dependency 3.0 instead of 2.0)

14: cannot load such file -- chef/mixin/language (windows cookbook dependency, 3.0 + for windows cookbook would fix this)

15: manual license acceptance required and cannot load such file -- chef/mixin/language error (windows cookbook dependency, 3.0 + for windows cookbook would fix this)
```

The big problem is that a bunch of under-maintained services use the older versions and upgrading any of them is likely to cause multitudes of problems throughout the chef org, so I want to have just this server use a newer version of either the windows or 7-zip cookbook.

What I tried to do to solve for this was created a new cookbook "all-servers-dev" and created dev versions of all the cookbooks in the dependency tree all the way down to "windows" where I downloaded the updated windows cookbook and replaced it at the bottom of the dependency tree. This didn't work however because chef keeps trying to sync all cookbooks even the windows one even though it's not included anywhere in the dependency tree that I can find.

I even tried removing the all-servers recipe and just installing the connector recipe whose only dependency is yum-epel whose only dependency is "compat_resource" which has no dependencies.

13.12.14

```
================================================================================
Recipe Compile Error in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/seven_zip/attributes/default.rb
================================================================================

NoMethodError
-------------
undefined method `kernel' for #<Chef::Node::Attribute:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx>

Cookbook Trace:
---------------
  /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/seven_zip/attributes/default.rb:21:in `from_file'

Relevant File Content:
----------------------
/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/seven_zip/attributes/default.rb:

 14:  # Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 15:  # distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 16:  # WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 17:  # See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 18:  # limitations under the License.
 19:  #
 20:  
 21>> if kernel['machine'] =~ /x86_64/
 22:    default['seven_zip']['url']          = 'http://www.7-zip.org/a/7z1514-x64.msi'
 23:    default['seven_zip']['checksum']     = 'xxxxxxxxxx'
 24:    default['seven_zip']['package_name'] = '7-Zip 15.14 (x64 edition)'
 25:  else
 26:    default['seven_zip']['url']          = 'http://www.7-zip.org/a/7z1514.msi'
 27:    default['seven_zip']['checksum']     = 'xxxxxxxxxx'
 28:    default['seven_zip']['package_name'] = '7-Zip 15.14'
 29:  end
 30:  

System Info:
------------
chef_version=13.12.14
platform=amazon
platform_version=2017.03
ruby=ruby 2.4.5p335 (2018-10-18 revision 65137) [x86_64-linux]
program_name=chef-client worker: ppid=3493;start=17:29:14;
executable=/opt/chef/bin/chef-client


Running handlers:
[2019-12-04T17:29:32+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
Running handlers complete
[2019-12-04T17:29:32+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 17 seconds
[2019-12-04T17:29:32+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2019-12-04T17:29:32+00:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
[2019-12-04T17:29:32+00:00] ERROR: undefined method `kernel' for #<Chef::Node::Attribute:xxxxxxxxxx>
[2019-12-04T17:29:32+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

14.14.29

```
================================================================================
Recipe Compile Error in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/windows/libraries/windows_package.rb
================================================================================

LoadError
---------
cannot load such file -- chef/mixin/language

Cookbook Trace:
---------------
  /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/windows/libraries/windows_package.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'

Relevant File Content:
----------------------
/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/windows/libraries/windows_package.rb:

  1:  require 'chef/resource/lwrp_base'
  2:  require 'chef/provider/lwrp_base'
  3:  
  4:  require 'win32/registry' if RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /mswin|mingw32|windows/
  5:  
  6:  require 'chef/mixin/shell_out'
  7>> require 'chef/mixin/language'
  8:  class Chef
  9:    class Provider
 10:      class WindowsCookbookPackage < Chef::Provider::LWRPBase
 11:        include Chef::Mixin::ShellOut
 12:        include Windows::Helper
 13:  
 14:        # the logic in all action methods mirror that of
 15:        # the Chef::Provider::Package which will make
 16:        # refactoring into core chef easy

System Info:
------------
chef_version=14.14.29
platform=amazon
platform_version=2017.03
ruby=ruby 2.5.7p206 (2019-10-01 revision 67816) [x86_64-linux]
program_name=/usr/bin/chef-client
executable=/opt/chef/bin/chef-client


Running handlers:
[2019-12-04T18:06:28+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
Running handlers complete
[2019-12-04T18:06:28+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 35 seconds
[2019-12-04T18:06:28+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2019-12-04T18:06:28+00:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
[2019-12-04T18:06:28+00:00] FATAL: LoadError: cannot load such file -- chef/mixin/language
```

15.5.17
Chef has a new prompt that’s unhandled by knife bootstrap:

```
Do you accept the 2 product licenses (yes/no)?
```

You can’t accept these from the bootstrap CLI, so you have to ssh to the server and run chef manually which then results in the same error as 14:

```
================================================================================
Recipe Compile Error in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/windows/libraries/windows_package.rb
================================================================================

LoadError
---------
cannot load such file -- chef/mixin/language

Cookbook Trace:
---------------
  /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/windows/libraries/windows_package.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'

Relevant File Content:
----------------------
/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/windows/libraries/windows_package.rb:

  1:  require 'chef/resource/lwrp_base'
  2:  require 'chef/provider/lwrp_base'
  3:  
  4:  require 'win32/registry' if RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /mswin|mingw32|windows/
  5:  
  6:  require 'chef/mixin/shell_out'
  7>> require 'chef/mixin/language'
  8:  class Chef
  9:    class Provider
 10:      class WindowsCookbookPackage < Chef::Provider::LWRPBase
 11:        include Chef::Mixin::ShellOut
 12:        include Windows::Helper
 13:  
 14:        # the logic in all action methods mirror that of
 15:        # the Chef::Provider::Package which will make
 16:        # refactoring into core chef easy

System Info:
------------
chef_version=15.5.17
platform=amazon
platform_version=2017.03
ruby=ruby 2.6.5p114 (2019-10-01 revision 67812) [x86_64-linux]
program_name=/usr/bin/chef-client
executable=/opt/chef/bin/chef-client


Running handlers:
[2019-12-04T18:14:03+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
Running handlers complete
[2019-12-04T18:14:03+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
Chef Infra Client failed. 0 resources updated in 18 seconds
[2019-12-04T18:14:03+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2019-12-04T18:14:03+00:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
[2019-12-04T18:14:03+00:00] FATAL: LoadError: cannot load such file -- chef/mixin/language
```

Comment: If chef-client is syncing the windows cookbook then it is a dependency somewhere.  This is why using a role cookbook pattern with berkshelf or policyfiles can be useful because the entire solved graph will be in the Berkshelf.lock or Policyfile.lock.json file.  That would also give you a single administrative point to be able to equality pin cookbooks to working versions.  Otherwise what you are asking for is not possible via just knife.

Comment: Does your Chef Server support policyfiles?

Comment: How would I find out?

Comment: lamont, I removed all the dependencies to the problematic windows cookbook from my cookbook and pointed them all at different versions and now both are being synced which results in the same problem

Comment: @Cdhippen Just what is your Chef Server version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 15.5.17 Chef has a new prompt that’s unhandled by knife bootstrap:
>
> ```
> Do you accept the 2 product licenses (yes/no)?
> ```
>
> You can’t accept these from the bootstrap CLI, so you have to ssh to
>   the server and run chef manually

that is incorrect, you can use [`--chef-license accept`](https://docs.chef.io/chef_license_accept.html#workstation-products) when you bootstrap the node to accept the chef license

if i understood your right, you wish to pin the different versions of the same cookbooks collection. if that is the case, you can acheive it by using [environment](https://docs.chef.io/environments.html#cookbook-pinning):

> Cookbook versions can be pinned in each environment, which allows you to control the rollout of new cookbook releases through successive testing environments before releasing new cookbook versions into production environments. See the environment format examples below for the cookbook pinning syntax.

so just remember to associate your nodes with specific chef environment, such that each environment has its own cookbook collection.

Comment: I should be able to work around with the staging environment as long as I'm not editing other cookbooks, but I only have the two pinned "connector" and "all-servers-dev" but it still tries to sync all the other cookbooks with it. Am I assuming this format correctly for pinning?
{
  "name": "staging",
  "description": "",           
  "cookbook_versions": {
    "all-servers-dev": "= 0.0.3",    
    "chef-client-dev": "= 4.3.3",
    "connector": "= 1.1.1"
  },.........

Comment: @Cdhippen: not following you. are you taking advantage of chef environment?

Comment: Are you talking about when you do knife environment edit <environment_name> ? That's the syntax I've been using to mess with the prod/ staging environments and what cookbooks they use

Comment: @Cdhippen: i've update my answer to help you accepting the license

Comment: I was able to accept the license but I'm still not really sure how I would take advantage of the environment, since I tried editing the environment to remove the cookbooks that were causing problems but it didn't do anything

Comment: @Cdhippen: rather than removing the cookbook, pin them to specific version. also, if my answer helped you, please accept it.

Comment: If I updated the cookbook wouldn't I have to make sure it's pinned correctly in all chef environments or risk breaking stuff in other environments? My original goal was to replace a few cookbooks with alternate versions *and* names and simply exclude the ones that are breaking my bootstrap, I'm not entirely sure but the suggestion to upgrade the cookbook sounds risky and time consuming

Comment: The biggest problem is that I want every other host that's using this chef server to keep using the exact same versions of the same cookbooks because I don't want to break stuff that's not mine